# JSF файл не видит CDI класс и его поля

Tags: java, jsf

Всем привет. Стараюсь активно учить Java. Есть совсем небольшой проект, чтобы познакомиться с JSF + CDI.
Вот структура проекта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержимое файла example.xhtml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>#{ExampleBean.title}</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
     <h:outputText value="#{ExampleBean.text}" />
</h:body>
</html>
```

Класс из которого хочу получить поля:

```
package webapp;

import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
public class ExampleBean {
    private String text = "CDI example";
    private String title = "Welcome to the club, Buddy";

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Проблема: При запуске сервера и перехода на веб страничку localhost.../example.xhtml получаю пустую страницу. Понял, что JSF файл не видит класс ExampleBean, но не могу понять почему.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А где папка WEB-INF? В ней обычно находится beans.xml, и - самое главное - web.xml. Я бы посоветовал погуглить простейший пример веб-приложения на JSF и запустить его, без каких-либо изменений, и только добившись его работоспособности начинать свои эксперименты.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что сам по себе `@Named` не делает класс видимым в CDI.
Нужно пометить класс одной из аннотаций для CDI в зависимости от того, какую зону видимости хотите получить для своего класса.
Стандартные аннотации:
`@Dependent`
`@RequestScoped`
`@ViewScoped`  (из пакета javax.faces.view)
`@ConversationScoped`
`@SessionScoped`
`@ApplicationScoped`

Не перепутайте с одноименными аннотациями JSF (аннотации cdi импортируются из пакета javax.enterprise.context, JSF из javax.faces.bean)

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ExampleBean {
```

В зависимости от настроек в `beans.xml` аннотация `@Dependent` может автоматически подразумеваться, если не указана явно никакая другая.

И если Вы не указываете имя явно в `@Named`, то именем бина будет имя класса с маленькой буквы: `#{exampleBean.text}`

Comment: Ответ неверен, указание области видимости необязательно для того, чтобы компонент стал управляться контейнером (т.е., стал видимым в `CDI`). Область видимости по-умолчанию (если не указано явно) - `@Dependent`, и с `JSF`-страницы **можно** обращаться к методам компонента, у которого область видимости не указана (хотя и `@Dependent` не часто является подходящим вариантом для `JSF`).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была не в отсутствии иных аннотация, помимо  @Named.
Я ошибся в 2-ух местах:
1) Пытался вызвать bean в example.xhtml, в то время, как писал я имя бина с большой буквы. 
2) Скорее всего были забыты подключёны cdi библиотеки. Ответ Сергея навёл меня на мысль о такой проблеме и я добавил в структуру проекта нужные джарники.

Спасибо большое всем за участие и терпение !